# git can not push/clone repo

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I can not push my local revision.

```
git.exe push --all --progress  "origin"

Counting objects: 80, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (55/55), 991.27 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 55 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To H:/BARE_GIT/stm32.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'H:/BARE_GIT/stm32.git'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (655 ms @ 23.03.2015 8:43:41)
```

Also, I can not clone new copy:

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "H:/BARE_GIT/stm32.git" "C:\stm32"

Cloning into 'C:\stm32'...
done.
**error: Could not read a2d1ce9ba8957ae0e21b3b7186e5426ebdb34107**

Success (2121 ms @ 23.03.2015 8:48:19)
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have write access

Comment: I believe it's an issue with permissions, are you supposed to be pushing to master or a different branch?